# using two different jquery version in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

i am using two different UI's in my application.
one UI supports jquery 1.7.1 version and another UI supports 1.10 version
For this I have implemented like

```
<link href="~/Scripts/themes/default-theme/ej.widgets.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/assets/js/ej.widgets.all.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/external/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
 </script>

<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/Kendo/Styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/Kendo/Styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

in the script I have defined like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $jq(document).ready(function () {
        $jq("#content").ejScroller({ height: 620 });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button").kendoButton();
   });
</script>
```

but my scroll bar is not loading.May I know where is the issue??

Comment: Check the console for errors. Ideally you shouldn't need to use two versions of jQuery in one site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the only problem, but you need to include your respective jQuery scripts before the UI library scripts that depend on them, i.e. jQuery 1.10 before ej.widgets and jQuery 1.7.1 before kendo.all.

Also note: [Kendo UI Q3 2013 should work with jQuery 1.10](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#jquery-version), so it would probably be wise to use that version so you can avoid having two versions of jQuery on the same page.

Comment: kendo controls not loading with jquery 1.10 version

Comment: @steve see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/97r6E/12/) - seems to work for me; as I said in my answer, are you sure you're including the jQuery script first?